# SQL concat and convert with first date

Tags: sql

Thanks a lot for your help in advance , under SQL I have one table with 4 columns : 
a- month with value data like 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

b- year with data like (2012-2013-2014-2018)

c-  client number with data like (1545112)

d- black listed with  amount value (1000-2000-3000)

I need a query to show only the first date in (mm-yyyy) format that the client appear in the table .
For Example attached here image for the table data
.
BR

[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried when as part of your question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood what you're asking for.

If you are trying to show just client id and the first date they appeared in desired format:

```
SELECT
    IDS,
    FORMAT(MIN(CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(4), [Year]) + '-'
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Month]) + '-1')), 'MM-yyyy') AS FirstDate
FROM TableName
GROUP BY IDS
```

If you are needing access to other columns (like black listed amount), you can find easily with window function:

```
SELECT IDS, FirstDate, Blacklisted
FROM (
    SELECT
        IDS,
        RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Month]), 2) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), [Year]) AS FirstDate,
        Blacklisted,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDS ORDER BY [Year], [Month]) AS RowId
    FROM @Data
    ) T
WHERE RowId = 1
```

Here is full script trying to simulate your test data:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    MONTH INT, YEAR INT, IDS INT, BLACKLISTED INT
)
INSERT @Data 
    SELECT 1, 2016, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2016, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2016, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2016, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 2016, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 2016, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 2016, 11364948, 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 8, 2015, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 8, 2016, 11364948, 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 9, 2015, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 10, 2015, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 11, 2015, 11364948, 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 12, 2015, 11364948, 1

SELECT
    IDS,
    FORMAT(MIN(CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(4), [Year]) + '-'
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Month]) + '-1')), 'MM-yyyy') AS FirstDate
FROM @Data
GROUP BY IDS

SELECT IDS, FirstDate, Blacklisted
FROM (
    SELECT
        IDS,
        RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Month]), 2) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), [Year]) AS FirstDate,
        Blacklisted,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDS ORDER BY [Year], [Month]) AS RowId
    FROM @Data
    ) T
WHERE RowId = 1
```